# Read files with extension .data into R

Tags: r, dataset

I need to read a data file into **R** for my assignment. You can download it from the following site.

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Acute+Inflammations

The data file ends with an extension .data which I never see before. I tried read.table and alike but could not read it into **R** properly. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a UTF-16 little endian file with a byte order mark at the beginning. `read.table` will fail unless you specify the correct encoding. This works for me on MacOS. Decimals are indicated by a comma.

```
read.table("diagnosis.data", fileEncoding="UTF-16", dec=",")

      V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
1   35.5  no yes  no  no  no  no  no
2   35.9  no  no yes yes yes yes  no
3   35.9  no yes  no  no  no  no  no
```

Answer (score 5):

From your link:

> The data is in an ASCII file. Attributes are separated by TAB.

Thus you need to use `read.table()` with `sep = "\t"`

> -- Attribute lines:  For example, '35,9   no  no  yes yes yes yes no'  Where:  '35,9' Temperature of patient  'no'    Occurrence of nausea 
>   'no'  Lumbar pain  'yes'  Urine pushing (continuous need for urination) 
>   'yes' Micturition pains  'yes'    Burning of urethra, itch, swelling of
>   urethra outlet  'yes' decision: Inflammation of urinary bladder 
>   'no'  decision: Nephritis of renal pelvis origin

Also looks like it uses a comma for the decimal, so also specify `dec = ","` inside `read.table()`.

It looks like you'll need to put in the column headings manually, though your link defines them.

Make sure you see @Gavin Simpson's comment below to clean up other undocumented "features" of this dataset.

Comment: I am unable to read the file using read.table or readLines. There are a few rogue characters at the beginning of the file, too.

Comment: That may or may not work however. I see `"15:56:01: The file "~/Downloads/diagnosis.data" is not valid UTF-8."` in my text editor, which is causing `read.table()` to error out on my Linux box. Opening the file in the editor, setting encoding to UTF-8 and resaving, allowed me to read the file with `read.table("~/Downloads/diagnosis.data", sep = "\t", dec = ",")`.

Comment: Seperator has "," in some .data files. Therefore `data <-read.table (file.choose (), fileEncoding =" UTF-8 ", sep =", ")` can be used. I used it like that. When I didn't do this I saw an extra "," at the end of each column.

Answer (score 3):

You have a UTF-16LE file, a.k.a Unicode on Windows (in case you're on that os).
Try this

```
f <-file("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/acute/diagnosis.data", open="r" ,encoding="UTF-16LE")
data <- read.table(f, dec=",", header=F)
```

Though trying what @Gavin Simpson said might help, as you can add your headings and save the file

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with file ".data", but I did well. Here is my code:

df <- read.table("diagnosis.data", fileEncoding = "UTF-8", sep = ",")

I hope this code can help you and others alot.

Answer (score 1):

The above responses are very useful. 
A bit trickier way is that you can just rename the file name or file type to .csv format. 
Then using the read.csv command you can do the rest.